# How to check if a string is at the start of a new line?

Tags: python, string, search

I am attempting to use the `find()` method within python, but have hit an issue. The `find()` method does not seem to allow you to only check for text on a newline. Code below:

```
def ParseText(self, text):
    endIndex = 0
    startIndex = text.find("\n/obj/item/clothing")

    while startIndex != -1:
        text = text[startIndex:]
        endIndex = text.find("\n/") 
        part = text

        if endIndex != -1:
            part = text[:endIndex]

        self.ParseItem(part)
        startIndex = text.find("/obj/item/clothing", endIndex)
```

`ParseText` is called with a file's full text, with new lines inside it. `ParseText` then looks for `/obj/item/clothing`, then calls `ParseItem` with extra text included.

Example of item code:
    `/obj/item/clothing/suit/armor/vest/ert
    name = "emergency response team armor"
    armor = list(melee=30, bullet=30, laser=30, energy=30, bomb=20, bio=0, rad=0)`

The search in `ParseText` has an issue. While it will detect this:

```
/obj/item/clothing/suit/armor/vest/ert
```

It will also detect this:

```
/datum/outfit/job/centcom/response_team/commander/amber
    suit = /obj/item/clothing/suit/armor/vest/ert/command
```

Note the whitespace and `suit =`. From what I can tell there is no way to check if a string starts exactly at a newline. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you bound to using `find() `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `re`:

```
>>> print(txt)

aaabbb
bbbaaa
aaaccc
cccaaa

>>> import re
>>> list(m.group(0) for m in re.finditer(r'^aaa.*', txt, re.MULTILINE))
['aaabbb', 'aaaccc']
```

so your code would be:

```
import re
...
class ???:
    pattern = re.compile(r'^/obj/item/clothing.*', re.MULTILINE)

    def ParseText(self, text):
        for match in self.pattern.finditer(text):
            self.ParseItem(match.group(0))
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm!
Any way I can get this to support indexes so I can pull data from nearby?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: IMO `re` is too much of a big cannon for simple check if a string **starts with** whatever substring. What about `str.startswith`?

Answer (score 1):

The first time you call find() should work correctly, when you include the newline character before the search term. I've noticed the second time you call it, you don't have that newline character. This would make it so that, after it finds the first one (starting on a newline), it will continue from there, and find any result, regardless of whether it starts on a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Checking line by line of a text (file) is done in python by simply iterating over it:

```
for line in textfile:
    if line.startswith('/obj/item/clothing'):
        ParseItem(line)
```

and if the text is already loaded into a string variable, you can split it easily into its lines with `str.splitlines()`
So then you'd do

```
for line in text.splitlines():
   ...
```